# React Hooks / Functional Component with Select Option Menu complains of breaking 'Rules of Hooks'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have 2 components, a Parent that contains the state and Child which has a select Dropdown that should modifies the state in the parent. When I try to inspect this component in React Dev tools / Components I get a warning "Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: ..." yet none of the reasons given seem to apply to my code.

Here is my code:

PARENT:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Child from './child'

const Parent = () => {
  const [gender, setGender] = useState('Men')

  const changeHandler = (value) => {
    console.log('Change Handler Fired', value)
    setGender(value)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Child gender={gender} onChange={changeHandler} />
    </>
  )
}

export default Parent
```

CHILD:

```
import React from 'react'

function Child({ gender, onChange }) {
  return (
    <select
      id="genders"
      name="gender"
      value={gender}
      onChange={(event) => onChange(event.target.value)}
    >
      <option key="Men" value="Men">
        Men
      </option>
      <option key="Women" value="Women">
        Women
      </option>
    </select>
  )
}

export default Child
```

The console warning suggests that the following could be why my component breaks:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

   - am using 16.9.0 of both react and react-dom.
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

   - I have read this `https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html` and can find no way I have broken the 'rules'
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

   - I Have used `npm ls react` and `npm ls react-dom`, my project only has one of each dep.

Can anybody help me understand how my code breaks the 'Rules of Hooks'?

Comment: is it possible to add a reproducible fiddle or StackBlitz? It could be due to other parent components as well.

Comment: i have tried your code out in codesandbox and i see no error https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-river-edtkh

Comment: Thanks for your codesandbox carrany, I was trying to set that up myself as requested by Prajwal. 
This does indeed seem to work, i should clarify and emphasize: the form also works when running in the browser in my local setup, its only when I try to inspect it in DevTools/Components does it complain about breaking the rule of hooks. 
Do you suppose this is a problem exclusive to React DevTools and not something I should worry about?

Comment: It seems to be something broader with my setup. If I open DevTools/Components and select some other components higher up the tree I get the same warning, even going up to my top level component (<Provider />) I get the warning. I'm clearly doing something wrong at a higher level. I am using React-Router and Redux in this project.

Comment: It turns out that the bundle was mounting twice due to a hand-coded <script> tag in my dev-env index.html file. Sorry for missing the wood for the trees and thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a manual `<script>` tag in the index.html file that was being used by my dev environment, this was causing 2 instances of the bundle to be mounted as I also have this mounted by webpack. The solution was to remove the manual script tag. It seems I was breaking Rule 3 or the Rules of Hooks: I had 2 instances of React & React.DOM running.